# Grouping based on multiple columns, computing frequency, and percentage

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let us say, I have the following data frame.

```
ID     Type   miles  
ID_1   Bus      2                    
ID_2   Taxi     3
ID_1   Bus      8
ID_2   Taxi     5   
ID_1   Car      6
ID_3   Train    5       
ID_4   Tram     7
```

I would like to group `ID` and `Type` and sum on `miles`. Then creating new column `mile_sum`.

Then, I would like to count occurrence `ID` and `Type` and put it on newly created column "Frequency".

Finally I would like to compute their percentage from Total and put on newly created "Percentage" column.

```
ID    Type    mile_sum   Frequency    Percentage
ID_1  Bus       10          2             28.5%                        
ID_2  Taxi      8           2             28.5%
ID_1  Car       6           1             14%
ID_3  Train     5           1             14%        
ID_4  Tram      7           1             14%
```

Can anyone help on this in Pandas Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregation for new column filled by `sum` and `counts`, then create new column with divide by `sum`, multiple by `100` and last if necessary use [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['ID','Type'], sort=False, as_index=False)
        .agg(mile_sum = ('miles','sum'), Frequency = ('miles','size')))
df['Percentage'] = df['Frequency'].div(df['Frequency'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)
print (df)
     ID   Type  mile_sum  Frequency  Percentage
0  ID_1    Bus        10          2        28.6
1  ID_2   Taxi         8          2        28.6
2  ID_1    Car         6          1        14.3
3  ID_3  Train         5          1        14.3
4  ID_4   Tram         7          1        14.3
```

If need percentage to numeric use:

```
df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'].astype(str) + '%'
print (df)
     ID   Type  mile_sum  Frequency Percentage
0  ID_1    Bus        10          2      28.6%
1  ID_2   Taxi         8          2      28.6%
2  ID_1    Car         6          1      14.3%
3  ID_3  Train         5          1      14.3%
4  ID_4   Tram         7          1      14.3%
```